# Read the data on Firebase and draw a line chart using library MpAndroidChart

Tags: java, firebase, mpandroidchart

---

Hi guys, I'm writing an app that will read the data stored in the Real-time Database of `Firebase` and draw a line chart with these data using libaray `MPAndroidChart` of Android Studio.

My data on the Real-time database is being obtained and uploaded with a `Python` script continuously which will gather the data of sensors on development board `Waspmote` from the serial port.(*This part may not be relative to my app as the data structure has been fixed on `Firebase`*)

The structure on the Real-time database is shown as follow:

[image]

Then here is my `MainActivity` code for the drawing app:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private LineChart Temp_linechart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        DatabaseReference mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Indoor");
        mPostReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Temp_linechart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.Data_of_Temp);
                final ArrayList<Entry> yData = new ArrayList<>();
                LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(yData,"Temp");

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                    float SensorValue = (float)ds.child("P1").getValue();
                    yData.add(new Entry(tsLong,SensorValue));
                }

                LineData data = new LineData (lineDataSet);
                Temp_linechart.setData(data);
                Temp_linechart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Temp_linechart.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to load post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

There is no error when running the code but when I open the app created on my phone, not line graph shows and the app will stopped after few seconds. shows:

`sensordata_vis` has stopped

### Please help, I'm really new to android studio. Thanks.

OK, after I applied `@Umar Hussain`'s method. The build was successful.
In `run` window, it shows[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfsti.png)[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6QAo.png)
And in `logcat` window, it shows[error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCvOa.png)[error4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhxsD.png)

Thanks

---

Finally, I have achieve what I want, here is my edited code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private LineChart Temp_linechart;
    ArrayList<Entry> yData;
    DatabaseReference mPostReference;
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Temp_linechart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.Data_of_Temp);

        mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Indoor");
        mPostReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener= new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                yData = new ArrayList<>();
                float i =0;
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    i=i+1;
                    String SV = ds.child("P1").getValue().toString();
                    Float SensorValue = Float.parseFloat(SV);
                    yData.add(new Entry(i,SensorValue));
                }
                final LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(yData,"Temp");
                LineData data = new LineData(lineDataSet);
                Temp_linechart.setData(data);
                Temp_linechart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Temp_linechart.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: move `Temp_linechart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.Data_of_Temp);` into `onCreate()` and move the rest of the code elsewhere, most definitely not `onStart()`. while `sensordata_vis has stopped` is not exactly an error description, which would permit an answer; please check the logcat and provide some more details.

Comment: I have modified my post with error pictures. Both `logcat` and `run` windows.

Answer (score 0):

First move your code to get reference of chart outside of the listener, to `onCreate()`.

Also move the MpAndroidChart Initialization into the oncreate method.

```
 final ArrayList<Entry> yData;
 LineDataSet lineDataSet;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Temp_linechart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.Data_of_Temp);
        yData = new ArrayList<>();
        lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(yData,"Temp");
        LineData data = new LineData (lineDataSet);
        Temp_linechart.setData(data);
        Temp_linechart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Temp_linechart.invalidate();

    }
```

Next inside your value event listener, only clear the array list and re populate it. And call the notify and invalidate on chart.

```
DatabaseReference mPostReference;
ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Indoor");
        mPostReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                yData.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                    float SensorValue = (float)ds.child("P1").getValue();
                    yData.add(new Entry(tsLong,SensorValue));
                }
                Temp_linechart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Temp_linechart.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to load post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Finally in your onStop remove the listener as the listener is not bind with fragment or activity life cycle you have to manually do it.

P.S: try to use Camelcase in Java as its the most common style used by Java devs and easy to read for us.

Comment: Can I just abandon the usage of `onStart()` and put the rest code outside the `onCreate` function. As I have no idea how to set the `onStop` activity.

Comment: You just need to override the onStop function and add the functionality: `mPostReference.removeValueEventListener(valueEventListener);`. Also its better to move the code of `onStart` to `onResume`. See the life cycle of android diagram: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: After I applied these changes, the build was OK, In run window, it shows `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process:com.example.zzzch.sensordata_vis, PID:8517  java.lang.IndexOutofBoundsException: Index:0, Size:0`

Comment: OK and Thanks, I have edited my post with picture of errors.

Comment: comment out the last line of onCreate method and try. your code is exactly like mine, only I was using the pie charts.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Always shows `sensordata_vis` keeps stopping

Comment: seeing your data structure picture, not every node has "P1". It should give an error when you try to convert to float. Is there any erro suggesting its not able to convert into float ?

Comment: No, I didn't find such error, I prepare to restructure the data, put p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 into one child to see whether it works.

Comment: It still doesn't work after I change the structure. With P1,P2,P3,P4,P5 in one child. The app still keep showing `sensordata_vis` has stopped

Comment: using an adapter with the chart would be rather proper... and please consult the Activity Lifecycle once, to understand when these methods are called.